# C#: Sandboxing and performance (MarshalByRefObject)

Tags: c#, .net, sandbox

I've written a very basic web server in C# that loads custom modules that handle requests to a specific domain name, as specified in a config file.  The custom modules are loaded into a new AppDomain because I need the ability to unload them dynamically (good for security, too).  Because modules are loaded into a new AppDomain all parameters and return types are MarshalByRefObject.  This works fine and I pass a HttpRequest object that inherits from MarshalByRefObject and return a LinkedList that is sent back to the client by the web server.

All of this works well, but a lot of the data is passed as byte[] and I believe the proxy for MarshalByRefObject will copy all of the bytes from the new AppDomain to the main AppDomain instead of accessing them directly.  So, if I'm right about this, if one of the modules would send a 5MB file as a response then 5MB would be loaded/generated in the module, then copied from the modules AppDomain to the main AppDomain and finally sent through the socket back to the client.

So, my question is: can I get around this somehow so it doesn't copy so much data between AppDomain's?  Or is there a better way to do this that doesn't use MarshalByRefObject?

Comment: Marshal the socket instead of the data.  Not sure how to do that, SocketInformation looks tempting.

Comment: That works :)  I had thought of that, but was figuring there was no way to serialize a socket (still technically true).  I just used Socket.DuplicateAndClose to get the SocketInformation (which is serializable) and use it to create the socket in the new AppDomain.  Thanks.

Comment: Do us a favor and write an answer.  The AndClose is what confuzzled me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up passing the SocketInformation to the new AppDomain and creating a new socket object there (in the new AppDomain).

In my "Sandbox wrapper object" I have this function:

```
internal class Sandbox
{
    private AppDomain _AppDomain;
    private WebApplicationProxy _Proxy;

    public Sandbox(string assemblyFile)
    {
        _AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        _Proxy = (WebApplicationProxy)_AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                                                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                                                    "WebServer.WebApplication.Proxy");
        _Proxy.Initialize(assemblyFile);
    }
    public void SendResponse(Socket client, HttpRequest request)
    {
        SocketInformation clientInfo = client.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        _Proxy.GetResponse(clientInfo, request);
    }
}
```

And in the new AppDomain "resumes" the socket, I'm not sure yet what actually happens behind the scenes... here's the code:

```
internal class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private AppController _AppController;

    public void Initialize(string assemblyFile)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFile);
        var q = from t in asm.GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(AppController))
                      && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass
                select t;
        foreach (Type t in q)
        {
            _AppController = (AppController)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        }
    }

    public void SendResponse(SocketInformation clientInfo, HttpRequest req)
    {
        Socket client = new Socket(clientInfo);

        LinkedList<byte[]> toSend = _AppController.GetResponse(client, req);

        foreach (byte[] bytes in toSend)
            client.Send(bytes);

        client.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the details of what happens when `DuplicateAndClose` is invoked, or creating the new Socket object in the new domain, but it is working well so far.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are per-process rather than per-appdomain (for performance reasons).  If html/xml are being passed around (and not binary data), you could change your api to use Strings instead of byte [].  You might even be able to support strings in the common case and byte[] in the binary cases.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't know string were treated that way, and most of the time it will be string data, although I still need to support binary data and it would be nice if that were efficient as well.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Extraordinary claims like this require extraordinary evidence.  Maybe it is true for interned strings, big if, the OP certainly won't be handling interned strings.

Comment: Does your socket library allow you to write to the socket from a different AppDomain?

Comment: @Hans Passant.  Good point.  I don't have the Jeffrey Richter book in front of me, but I think the implementors decided that since strings are (supposed to be) immutable, there was no compelling reason to copy strings between AppDomains in the same process.

Comment: Immutability is not the only concern. Garbage collection is another. AFAIK AppDomains have separate GCs, so I don't know how you would share strings between them.

Comment: From Jeffrey Richter's "CLR Via C# 2" p. 538, "When marshaling a String object across an AppDomain boundary, the CLR just passes the reference to the String object accross the boundary; it does not make a copy of the String object.  The CLR can offer this optimization because String objects are immutable, and therefore, it is impossible for code in one AppDomain to corrupt a String object's characters."

Answer (score 1):

If this is .NET 4.0 would using a [Memory mapped file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx) be an option?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0, do you mean writing to the memory mapped file from one AppDomain and reading it from the other?

Comment: Yes, specifically for the larger files.  Although 5mb may not be large enough for you to see a benefit I thought it might be worthy of consideration.